# How to communicate with WebDriver from the browser instance?

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, automated-tests

I need a way to trigger an event (or something like that) in a WebDriver to persist some data after a redirect.

[WebDriver docs](http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/eventhandling.html) describe some events but it turns out they're internal WD events and have nothing to do with the page the instance is currently viewing. `browser.execute` is useful to a degree but not in this case - event needs to be fired AFTER a click which ultimately causes a redirect but before the actual redirect. This is not possible to catch with `browser.execute`.

More specifically, there's an object on page A which I need to persist to page B but once a redirect on page A occurs, the object is lost. Using localStorage isn't an option so I need a way to communicate with WebDriver.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: What is an object and what exactly you want to do with this object?

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov It's just a codecoverage object. I need to retrieve it before the redirect actuates; otherwise it's lost on the final page.

Comment: Could you please provide a code example. I don't know what is `codecoverage object`?

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov I can write some pseudocode if that helps; the question is how do I send a message from a browser instance to the selenium script? Don't worry too much about the code coverage object.